# Jscroll not display trigger option (load more option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I am using a jscroll JQuery plugin. I have to use `autotriggeruntil: 3`, but it's not displaying, it loads more options instead of loading all content. Why?

Here is my code:

```
$('#product-grid').jscroll({
        autotrigger: true,
        autotriggeruntil: 3,
        pagingselector: '.next-page a',
        nextselector: '.next-page a',
        contentselector: '.test',
    });
```

please suggest to me how can I do this?

Regards,

vinit

Comment: can you show your html

Comment: It's hard to tell becouse there no `HTML` but you could try this:
1. remove last comma from `contentselector`;
2. remove all elements except `autotriggeruntil`;
3. call `jscroll` when page loaded;

Comment: @MindaugasVečkys thank you for help there is my mistake so it's not come now it's working thank, but i have 1 more issue if you can help. now i am using this on product list page here all product are come in grid view but when i scroll down there is lazy loding image which is put by me but it's keep loding untill i don't scroll down why? how can i stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution.

here i have hide paging elements, so next link is not display,so here i just show a next link and hide other element so it's works fine.

Regards,
vinit

Comment: Whats the exact solution ...where to put??